# How to get json response using system.net.webrequest in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, webrequest

I need to get *json* data from an external domain.
I used **WebRequest** to get the response from a website.
Here's the code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
string text;
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Does anyone know why I can't get the *json* data?

Comment: anyone knows why i cant get the json data?

Comment: You need `using (var response = request.GetResponse()){ ... }`. May not solve the problem but saves the resource leak.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to explicitly ask for the content type.

Add this line:

```
 request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

At the appropriate place

Comment: Is it possible to pass the parameter with this request??

Comment: Request Content-Type describes type of request body. It is used to tell the server in what format the data is being sent to server. It has nothing to do with content type of response. The client may ask to reply with specific types using `Accept` header, but the server may ignore it for other reasons.

Comment: Yes Jidheesh, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263082/how-to-pass-post-parameters-to-asp-net-web-request

Comment: I know this is an old answer but for completeness wanted to reply to @SHEKHARSHETE:  you can use something like the excellent NewtonSoft JSON.Net which will do the work for you and I recommend reading the useful guides to workout how to do this here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 76):

Some APIs want you to supply the **appropriate "Accept" header** in the request to get the wanted response type.

For example if an API can return data in XML and JSON and you want the JSON result, you would need to set the [`HttpWebRequest.Accept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept.aspx) property to **"application/json"**.

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the parameter with this??

Comment: Perhaps you can try to add your parameters to `requestUri` I.e. localhost/api/product/123

Comment: @JidheeshRajan See this question/answers for how to add parameters to a `WebRequest` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279888/how-to-add-parameters-into-a-webrequest

Comment: Adding only request.ContentType = "application/json; wasn't enough  for me so I think your solution is the correct one.

Comment: This answer should be accepted because the current accepted answer is not correct. Another example of not using "Accept" when appropriate...