# Add param POST request using HttpWebRequest async windows phone 8 - JSON

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

I want to add params to my request, how can I do it?
I read a lot about how, but nothing works.

I have this code:
http://pastebin.com/XVp8iTbR

I would know how I can add data in my query.

I would know how convert result (JSON) in C# object or array or something friendly.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using HttpWebRequest, not WebRequest. request.GetRequestStream() don't exists.

Comment: [HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) I think it exists.

Comment: This has been asked and [**answered**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18838148/416518) several times on this site.