# Properly handling exceptions generated by WebRequest and WebReponse in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

While browsing through the MS examples and Stackoverlow examples on how to handle exceptions generated by `WebRequest` (`HttpWebRequest`) and `WebReponse`(`HttpWebResponse`), I found a lot of examples that either handle exceptions or don't handle exceptions.

One example, I found very interesting was https://stackoverflow.com/a/137300/465292
`using` within `using`

Another, example (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279967/465292)

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri) as HttpWebRequest;
                  if (request != null)
```

seems bogus to me, since no where in doc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, `WebRequest.Create()` returns `null`

Microsoft own example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es54hw8e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1, places both `WebRequest` & `WebReponse` in one try block.

Comment: For your "another case": `WebRequest.Create("ftp://some.site") as HttpWebRequest` will indeed return null - "The Create method returns a descendant of the WebRequest", but not necessary `HttpWebRequest` all the time.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Well, if WebRequest.Create("address") returns null, that means scheme is not supported. Wouldn't it better to just let `WebRequest.Create()` throw `NotSupportedException` exception ?
Edit: well, Not necessary...... if you request ftp address, and expect `HttpWebRequest` as response(`as HttpWebRequest`), that yes. `null` would be a better choice !

Answer (score 1):

In short, it depends. The point of a `try` / `catch` block is if you think you can recover from the exception thrown at that point in time. I.e. Will you be re-trying as you suspect the web call should work and want to give it a couple of goes before giving up?

This is a case by case basis. If an exception occurs and you cannot / do not want to handle it then don't bother wrapping in `try` / `catch` and let it go up until something can handle it.

As with `using` this allows you to release memory and nested `usings` are fine as it ensures you are disposing of objects where possible. Of course, depending on what you do you might want to go down the `try` / `catch` / `finally` and `dispose` explicitly in `finally` but again, a case by case deal.