# C# Post data to URI and save html response

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to Post some data to a URI and read the returned html content. I have found this code, but need to extend it to include my parameters. Any idea how to do this?

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.asp.net"); 
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse(); 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()); 
string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass POST parameters to ASP.Net web request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263082/how-to-pass-post-parameters-to-asp-net-web-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stream to write content to webrequest

```
string data = "username=<value>&password=<value>"; //replace <value>
    byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    private string urlPath = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/manager/";
    string request = urlPath + "index.php/org/get_org_form";
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;  
    Stream newStream=webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(dataStream,0,dataStream.Length);
    newStream.Close();
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Or this link [.NET: Simplest way to send POST with data and read response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088625/net-simplest-way-to-send-post-with-data-and-read-response) may help you more