# web request using API

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, information-retrieval

I have done something similar to this before however I'm not sure how to do this with a bigger project.
I'm trying to return the titles of all the stuff on the front page of reddit.

From this site:

http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json

I pasted the data into

http://json2csharp.com/#

to find out the class I need.

From here though, I'm not too sure on how to proceed. If I wanted to return an array of all this data so I can easily get information, how could I do it.
Sorry for the vagueness of this question but I'm just at a loss and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json");
}
```

For old .[Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108297/how-to-get-json-response-using-system-net-webrequest-in-c):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
string text;
 request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I get an error on the new System.Net.WebClient, says that it doesn't exist in the namespace and I can't import it.

Comment: In       System.Net.WebClient

Comment: @AndyOHart http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: .Net for me only has Http and NetworkInformation, cant import WebClient :S 
This is for a Windows store app so maybe thats why?

Comment: @AndyOHart What is you .net vesrion

Comment: Thanks for that.
Im getting an error on:

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync();

It says  Cannot convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.WebResponse>' to 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse' 

Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44562/discussion-between-shahrooz-jefri--and-andyohart)