# Get JSON string from HTTP GET request

Tags: c#, json, http, fiddler

Using fiddler to observe this URL:
http://opencaselist.paperlessdebate.com/bin/AllDocs?view=attachments#format=json?|t=allattachments&p=1&l=10&s=filename&d=asc

I find a nice JSON response like this
[image]

How do I get this response into a string that I can save in a txt file using C#? Is there a way to turn an HTTP Web Response to a string? Is there something is NewtonSoft JSON that can help me? Are there particular terms that will help me google this more effectively?

Every time I try I just get an HTML version of the web-page at the link and not the JSON data I'm trying to get:

```
    string url = "http://opencaselist.paperlessdebate.com/bin/AllDocs?view=attachments#|t=allattachments&p=1&l=10&s=filename&d=asc";

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108297/how-to-get-json-response-using-system-net-webrequest-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that on that screenshot, there are some differences:

- the URL is way different: `AllAttachements` vs `AllDocs`, but that's minor, I'm pointing it out "just in case"
- the PARAMS are way different: the screenshot specifies `xpage=plain&outputSyntax=plain` and your code - not
- the HEADERS are different: your code has `Accept=text\json` while screenshot has `Accept: text/javascript`

Have you tried using **the same** params and headers?

EDIT: also, I've opened up the page from your code, and it actually is a page. After loading, it generates additional requests to

```
http://opencaselist.paperlessdebate.com/bin/get/XWiki/AllAttachmentsResults?xpage=plain&outputSyntax=plain&offset=1&limit=10&reqNo=1&sort=filename&dir=asc
```

which, if you download, results in JSON data. No headers at all, simple GET. I've just got the JSON data by simply pasting that URL into Chrome.. I think that you simply use wrong URL.

Comment: Oh. That makes a lot of sense - I just assumed that the URL fiddler was using was the same as the URL I was seeing in chrome. How you figured out my mistake so quickly is beyond me. I'm in awe.

Comment: Fiddler shows you *all* of the requests, including the AJAX requests, whose URLs are never shown in Chrome's address bar.